# Looking for an Eclipse Code Formatter

Tags: eclipse, plugins, formatter

I know the built in Codeformatter in Eclipse but there is one problem with it.

I work in a team of 20 developers and all confirmed to a codeformatting I do not like. E.g. the wrap lines after 80 characters or opening braces on the same line, etc.

So what I want is a formatter which formats the code in 2 ways: When I work on a class, I want the formatter to make me happy and when I push it to SVN it should format it so other wont be bothered.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you already have settings done in your machine. If so, then you can always export the preference via File -> EXPORT -> General/Preferences and ask your colleagues to import it.

If not, then try with this...

https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/source/browse/trunk/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

Moreover it is not really a good idea to format while checking it into SVN as it might bother the fellow developers who might not feel comfortable when lots of formatting changes for a minor one line bug fix.